# Java HhtmlUnit getByXPath() for relative search

Tags: java, htmlunit

I'm using HtmlUnits over Java to scrape my website.

I have the following div inside my HTML page:

```
<div class="items">
   <div class="item_title">
     <span class="title">TEXT</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I got the `HtmlDivision` object that contains the full div.
I'm trying to get to the `span` element using the

```
List<?> titleSpans = div.getByXPath("/span");
```

But this returns all the spans in the page.

How can I search for `span` elements that are only in this single `HtmlDivision` element?

Answer (score 1):

In XPath, regardless of what technology you use, a single slash (`/`) represents a full path from the root. In contrast, a double slash (`//`) is relative. Regardless if it is the first child under the current node, if you do not want to express a full path to the desired element, you must use a relative path. For you, that's `"//span"`.

If you want to use a more specific (relative) path, use a predicate. For example, `"//span[@class='title']"`

**UPDATE**:  To limit relative path to the current node, use the dot (`.`) before the double slash. For example `".//span[@class='title']"`

Comment: Thanks but this is actually the second child element. Is there a way for me to relatively search for span with a specific class name?

Comment: @AsafNevo I think I just answered that with the edit I made. If you have a more specific issue, let me know.

Comment: Is it possible that i'm using `HtmlDivision` object, with `div.getByXPath("//span[@class='title']");` but yet I receive back spans from all over the page and not only inside that particular div?

Comment: It also looks like that if i use your suggestion but with `.` at the beginning it works!
`".//span[@class='title']"`

Comment: "_but yet I receive back spans from all over the page and not only inside that particular div?_" Yes, I thought this was the intent. The dot (`.`) starts from the current node.

Comment: @AsafNevo the key giveaway 1) single slash was not going to work, and 2) The dot works from the current node. In conjunction with double slash, it's a relative path from the current node only.